# Simplify the jquery script for slider

Tags: jquery, html, css, loops

I have created a script where I am sliding few images
, I know I have used some static approach I want to make my script generic that no matter how many images I put it should work, my script is as follows. this fiddle animate properly here http://jsfiddle.net/tqnrcfcv/6/

```js
//Create a var to store the index of red element
var count = -1;
var count2 = 0;
var count3 = 1;
function active() {
  var img = $('div');
  var imgLength = img.length - 1;
  //Check if the actual item isn't more than the length then add 1 otherway restart to 0
  count < imgLength ? count++ : count=0;
  count2 < imgLength ? count2++ : count2=0;
  count3 < imgLength ? count3++ : count3=0;
  
  //Remove the class and add it to the new target
  img.eq(count).css({left:0, transform:'scale(1)', 'z-index':100});
  img.eq(count2).css({left:'60px', transform:'scale(.8)', 'z-index':50});
  img.eq(count3).css({left:'120px', transform:'scale(.6)', 'z-index':1});
}
setInterval(active, 1000);
```

```css
*{
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
.a,.b,.c{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:50px;
  left:0;
  box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  background:#f00;
  transform-origin:50% 100%;
  z-index:100;
}
.b{
  left:60px;
  transform:scale(.8);
  background:grey;
  z-index:50;
}
.c{
  left:120px;
  transform:scale(.6);
  background:yellow;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">
</div>
<div class="b">
</div>
<div class="c">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to dynamically do this. So you'd basically put all your images into an array, iterate over each one and give them their index and then iterate over them and check the conditionals.

Comment: Can you create an example please.